# One excel Sheet for each subreport (No groups in the main report)jaspersoft iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

This is really driving me mad.. I read everywhere but still can't understand why mine isn't working

I have a main report( a dummy query returning me only one row) and 2 subreports(each with its own header) found in two different detail band. The second subreport splits into multiple excel sheets!

The main report doesn't contain any groups.. its just a dummy query and has no links with the subreports.

This is what i did in the main report:

1. Add in Properties : Name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet "  with Value="True"
2. Set Ignore Pagination="True"
3. Added a Line element and set the Properties Expression: Name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row"  and Default Value="True"

Then for the second subreport:

1. Set Ignore Pagination="True"

I just want one excel sheet for each subreports. But the second subreport is being split to multiple sheets... :(

Does anybody know what's the problem...?

I also read an issue with ignore pagination and page breaks here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/ireport-designer/issues/2575

I am using the Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.0.1

======================================
My jrxml for the main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_Report28022013" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="1808a381-4204-4662-9cc0-7d154bcc0890">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/Test/Subreports"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://192.168.17.114:8080/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="True"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows" value="True"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Documents and Settings\\TreshmaC\\Desktop\\WCHY\\JasperSoft\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     tableliste."ident" AS tableliste_ident
FROM
     "public"."tableliste" tableliste
LIMIT 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="tableliste_ident" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="97" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="ea3a0ff6-f82f-43c0-8c7b-3d06e699f2f0" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="75"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:Sample_Report28022013_subreport1.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <break>
                <reportElement uuid="3568174b-2ea9-4973-8e12-adcb7f54685a" x="0" y="83" width="100" height="1"/>
            </break>
        </band>
        <band height="94" splitType="Prevent">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="b6ab1daa-122a-4a4b-8f60-f9fe2ba78204" x="0" y="13" width="555" height="72">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.before.row" value="True"/>
                </reportElement>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:Sample_Report28022013_subreport2.jrxml"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="203" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="2651da09-f5ff-45de-91cb-6d9f0a8af724" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="200"/>
                <mp:map xmlns:mp="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <mp:latitudeExpression><![CDATA[37.7750f]]></mp:latitudeExpression>
                    <mp:longitudeExpression><![CDATA[-122.4183f]]></mp:longitudeExpression>
                </mp:map>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

==================================================
jrxml  file for the second subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample_Report28022013_subreport2" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="5a86bc51-7425-4897-b74c-0dcf7016c666">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/Test/Subreports"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://192.168.17.114:8080/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows" value="True"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     ad_dcr."id_client" AS ad_dcr_id_client,
     ad_dcr."detail_obj_dem" AS ad_dcr_detail_obj_dem,
     ad_dcr."cre_mnt_octr" AS ad_dcr_cre_mnt_octr,
     ad_dcr."cre_mnt_deb" AS ad_dcr_cre_mnt_deb,
     ad_cli."id_client" AS ad_cli_id_client,
     ad_cli."num_port" AS ad_cli_num_port,
     ad_cli."pp_prenom" AS ad_cli_pp_prenom,
     ad_cli."pays" AS ad_cli_pays,
     ad_cli."email" AS ad_cli_email,
     ad_cli."pp_nom" AS ad_cli_pp_nom
FROM
     "public"."ad_cli" ad_cli LEFT JOIN "public"."ad_dcr" ad_dcr ON ad_cli."id_client" = ad_dcr."id_client"
ORDER BY ad_cli."id_client"]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ad_dcr_id_client" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ad_dcr_detail_obj_dem" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ad_dcr_cre_mnt_octr" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ad_dcr_cre_mnt_deb" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_id_client" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_num_port" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_pp_prenom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_pays" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ad_cli_pp_nom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="43" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a071e7c5-1a11-497b-9eee-6b243a947965" x="378" y="0" width="177" height="39"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Castellar" size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DCR ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement uuid="12e8ca58-2196-4a8a-9137-c5104e63a485" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" backcolor="#006666"/>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a1b68cab-e347-4a8f-87f8-01064a78854f" x="12" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Client ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="8a1870d5-2682-45a1-bf8b-31a613028daf" x="312" y="0" width="143" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Achat]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="df37206c-95bf-4d03-8add-3fc7ca1d07a9" x="455" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Montant]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="40e2dded-de55-4692-8e8d-2e94127dd28e" x="112" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nom]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="45abf217-95a0-4ef4-963b-45c2915e5723" x="212" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pays]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="26" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="7f43f0d2-fcc2-45b3-865e-02d643954c1c" x="12" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_dcr_id_client}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="c14584b6-c516-423a-ac17-bc4ffeb7d74c" x="312" y="0" width="143" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_dcr_detail_obj_dem}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#,##0.00">
                <reportElement uuid="88cb8587-2e82-4ea6-9c1d-f53767ffb93c" x="455" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_dcr_cre_mnt_deb}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="f4feb876-fbb5-4b7b-b9fb-f24528dfb762" x="112" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_cli_pp_nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="5fed5609-a23b-4cbe-a4b2-a0ebf36e3cd5" x="212" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ad_cli_pays}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="6eb43b44-1a3f-4b05-be37-4caeb35e5feb" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="8" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="7" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Hi onepotato added my jrxml file can you have a look please? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think You can just set the size of a page in main and sub reports to some very large value, for example 999999 and insert "page break" from pallete between sub-reports.
This way You should get each subreport in different page, but second one should not span across multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to do anthing in the Main. It´s all in the subreports. For example the main:

```
    <detail>
            <band height="397">
                <subreport>
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="298" width="801" height="99" uuid="61789fb8-f34c-46d4-a13e-6cfeba5567a7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="298" width="801" height="99" uuid="61789fb8-f34c-46d4-a13e-6cfeba5567a7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["repo:"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </detail>
```

And use in the last element you have (like a textfield) a BreakAfter:

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="120" height="30" uuid="632a6ed9-70ce-4ecd-a3e0-aaec6af95aa9">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name" value="Nombre y apellidos"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TOTAL"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

This sould be placed at the end of your report